# Checking for valid user memory in kernel mode with copy_to_user

Tags: linux-kernel

So, I tried using this:

```
copy_to_user(p, q, 0)
```

I want to copy from `q` to `p` and if it doesn't work, then I want to know if `p` points to an invalid address.

`copy_to_user` returns the number of bytes that weren't copied successfully but in this case, there are 0 bytes and I can't know for sure if `p` points to an invalid address.

Is there another way to check if `p` points to a valid user memory?

Comment: Phrase `invalid address` is useless without specifying size of access. For 0-size access every address is OK, so `copy_to_user` returns success in that case. You may use 1-byte copiing for check that at least one byte at given address is accessible.

Comment: What if I know the size of the block but I don't want to copy to it...I mean I dont want to use copy_to_user and I only need to check if the block is valid.

Comment: According to the sources, `copy_to_user` uses arch-dependent code for perform copiing. In theory you can reproduce that code in your module, but ... is check-only really needed? It is OK to just perform needed operation with given block. If it is succeed, then block is valid. If it is failed, then user have provided incorrect address, and error can be returned. Note, that for some user-space blocks copiing operation may cause page fault. And only the handler attached to the page can determine, whether access is OK or not. It is cannot be checked without  actual access.

Comment: Can you please include the architecture and kernel source (vanilla, and version)?  ARM has an `ldrt` instruction and there are marked sections/functions for handling a fault.  It is no use for someone to answer the question if you use some vendor linux that is non-standard.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to check passing size value manually each time before calling `copy_to_user()`. If it's 0 or not in valid range -- you shouldn't call `copy_to_user()` at all. This way you can rely on `copy_to_user()` return value.

Comment: How do I check it ? I tried access_ok but I got valid result for invalid pointers

Comment: You need to check size value, which is 0 in your case. And if it zero -- you shouldn't actually run `copy_to_user()`. Keep it simple :) And now when you are sure that size is bigger than 0, you can rely on result from `copy_to_user()` function and you can tell, if everything went ok or not.

Answer (score 0):

the method copy_to_user defined at /usr/src/linux-3.0.6-gentoo/include/asm-generic/uaccess.h

```
static inline long copy_to_user(void __user *to,
                const void *from, unsigned long n)
{
        might_fault();
        if (access_ok(VERIFY_WRITE, to, n))
                return __copy_to_user(to, from, n);
        else
                return n;
}
```

the method `access_ok` checks the accessibility of to(user memory). So you can use the method access_ok to check memory is valid or not(to is not NULL / it's in user space)?

Argument VERIFY_READ or VERIFY_WRITE. VERIFY_READ: identifies whether memory region is readable,  VERIFY_WRITE: identifies whether the memory region is readable as well as writable.
[source of method access_ok](https://xorl.wordpress.com/2010/10/25/linux-kernel-user-to-kernel-space-range-checks/)

Comment: In [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33638185/checking-for-valid-user-memory-in-kernel-mode-with-copy-to-user#comment55052774_33639356) asker says, that `access_ok` is not appropriate for him, because it doesn't check *access validness*.  Actually, `access_ok` only checks that given address **is not kernel one**.

Answer (score 0):

And what do you consider 'valid user memory'? What do you need this for?

Let's say we only care about the target buffer residing in userspace range (for archs with joint address spaces). From this alone we see that testing the address without the size is pointless - what if the address is the last byte of userspace? Appropriate /range/ check is done by access_ok.

Second part is whether there is a page there or a read/write can be performed without servicing a page fault. Is this of any concern for you? If you read copy_from/whatever you will see it performs the read/write and only catches the fault. There is definitely KPI to check whether the target page can be written to without a fault, but you would need to hold locks (mmap_sem and likely more) over your check and whatever you are going to do next, which is likely not what you wanted to do.

So far it seems you are trying